# java class and subclasses by using super

Tags: java

I have3 classes: class Item :

```
public class Item {
    public String name,constructor ; 
    public int year; 
    public double price ; 
    public Item(String name,int year,double price,String constructor){
        this.name = name ; 
        this.year = year ; 
        this.price = price ; 
        this.constructor = constructor ; 

    } 
    public String getName(){
        return name ; 
    } 
    public int getYear(){
        return year ; 

    } 
    public double getPrice(){
        return price ; 
    }
    public String getConstructor(){
        return constructor ; 
    } 
    public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name ; 
    }
    public void setYear(int year ){
       this.year = year ; 
    } 
    public void setPrice(double price){
       this.price = price ; 

    }
    public void setConstructor(String constructor){
       this.constructor = constructor ; 

    }
}
```

class Hardware:

```
public class Hardware extends Item {


private String proccesor;
private String motherboard;
private String RamMemory;
private String drive;

public Hardware(String name, int year,double price,  String constructor, String proccesor,String motherboard, String RamMemory, 
String drive) {
super(name, year, price, constructor);
this.proccesor= proccesor;
this.motherboard= motherboard;
this.RamMemory= RamMemory;
this.drive= drive;
}

public void setProccesor (String proccesor) {
this.proccesor= proccesor;
}

public void setMotherboard(String motherboard){
this.motherboard= motherboard;
}

public void setRam(String RamMemory){
this.RamMemory= RamMemory;
}

public void setDrive(String drive){
this.drive= drive;
}

public String getProccesor() {
return proccesor;
}

public String getMotherboard() {
return motherboard;
}

public String getRamMemory() {
return RamMemory;
}

public String getDrive() {
return drive;
}





}
```

and class Proccesor:

```
public class Proccesor extends Hardware {

private double ghz;
private int cores;

public Proccesor (String name, int year,double price,  String constructor,  double ghz, int cores) {
super(super(name,year, price, constructor));
this.ghz= ghz;
this.cores= cores;
}

public void setGhz(double ghz){
this.ghz= ghz;
}

public void setCores(int cores) {
this.cores = cores;
}

public double getGHz() {
return ghz;
}

public int getCores() {
return cores;
}
}
```

I need to call the constructor of the Item class into the Proccesor class but i dont know how  to do it. Command **super(super(name,year, price, constructor));** gives me the error:

```
Proccesor.java:7: error: call to super must be first statement in constructor
super(super(name,year, price, constructor));
           ^
1 error
```

Comment: What do you think `super(super(..))` would do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `super(super(..))`.

You should only from class Processor call the constructor of your super class, then it will be in charge of calling the constructor of the `Item` class.

If you need to bypass the constructor of Hardware, then Hardware should have a protected constructor that is designed to call the Item constructor and can be called by subclasses.

```
public Hardware(String name, int year,double price,  String constructor, String proccesor,String motherboard, String RamMemory, String drive) {
    this(name, year, price, constructor);
    this.proccesor= proccesor;
    this.motherboard= motherboard;
    this.RamMemory= RamMemory;
    this.drive= drive;
}

protected Hardware(String name, int year,double price,  String constructor) {
    super(name, year, price, constructor);
}
```

And, as you can see :

- a class can have multiple constructors
- it's possible to put common code in one of them (usually the simplest) and call it from others to avoid code deduplication.

That's what the `this(name, year, price, constructor);` statement means.

And indent your code better, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `super()`, the superconstructor of `Processor` (`Hardware`) will call the constructor of Item.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use super(super(name,year, price, constructor));
Just use super(name,year, price, constructor) and it will call all another constructors with super successively

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, `super(super(...` is not a valid java syntax. Now, think about it:

Look at your `Hardware` constructor.

Having *only* this constructor you explicitly allow to create `Hardware` objects *Only by supplying all* the constructor params, including `String processor` and `motherboard`.

Now, because your `Processor` is also a `Hardware` it can only be constructed by supplying all necessary information to its `super(...)` constructor.

What you could do, for example :

1. make additional another constructor in `Hardware` which will allow you to construct objects with less params, and call it from `Processor`'s constructor.

   or
2. call `super(name, year, price,  constructor, proccesor, motherboard, RamMemory, drive)`
   (with full params list) when constructing `Processor`, perhaps passing some default values for params unused in `Processor`, such as `drive`.